# Why did Whiterose let Grant kill himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In Season 3 finale of *Mr. Robot*, where Elliot, Darlene and Dom are held captive by Leon and dark army, Grant wanted to kill Aldersons and has Whiterose's permission but Elliot talks to Whiterose about a way to speed up shifting the base (or HQ) to Congo as fast as possible. Whiterose accepts this and orders Grant to stop this but instead hints him to die.

I didn't quite understand this. In the previous episode she accepts Grant's proposal to kill Elliot but later orders the otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

White Rose was frustrated with the delays in getting her project moved to the Congo.  When Elliot announced that he had  hacked the Dark Army and come up with a plan that could get the project moved to the Congo *quickly,* she was intrigued, and changed her mind about killing him.  As Elliot said:

> I pulled off something in ONE DAY that you've been trying to accomplish for months!

*(Referring to his previous activities, but it does set a precedent for what he can do, when he says he can get the project moved ASAP.)*

It helps to remember how important **time** is to White Rose.  She has been known to get upset about wasted *seconds* and the delays in moving the project to the Congo were, IIRC, on the order of *days* thus far, and looking like it might be even longer.

Knowing how Grant feels about Elliot, White Rose evidently decided that his likely reaction to sparing the Aldersons (ie: complaining; butting heads with Elliot) would cause even more delays, of which she already had too many.  AS White Rose says in the finale:

> Your jealousy has always blinded you to Mr Alderson's value

Rather than deal with more of his attitude regarding Elliot, she simply had him kill himself, instead.  It was a question of efficiency.

Comment: Thanks very much. Has the series moved on from Psych-Thriller to Sci-Fi-Psych-Thriller, considering the above scenario and the post-end scene?

Comment: @K-devlife10 I certainly hope it's not moving into sci-fi territory, myself.  One of the things I like about this show is how *realistic* the science is (at least regarding hacking.)  Although, White Rose certainly seems to believe in some sci-fi theories, and this show **is** known for using the *unreliable narrator* trope, so we may well see some sci-fi-ish stuff happening before a mid-season reveal that it was all someone's imagination.

Comment: thanks! I hope that Mr.Robot remains as realistic as possible without actually creeping in the Sci-Fi domain as well.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Steve-O says (which I think is spot on), White Rose appears to believe that she's creating some sort of device that will be able to manipulate time. She tells Grant that she will find him, implying that after he kills himself, she will go back in time and find him again and reward him. This is also how she lures Angela into her plan – by telling her (or at least hinting) that she may be able to go back and see her dead mother again, which is the one thing in the world she wants the most.

Given her belief that she will one day be able to manipulate time, death becomes almost meaningless to her. She'll simply go back and make things happen differently once she's perfected time travel.

Comment: yeah, even I suspected that. I've added a comment above. Hope you all can enlighten me a little more.